# Grails: examples of good use of .memoize()?

Tags: grails, groovy, memoization

What would be the syntax for memoizing a service method that is side-effect free and only does lookups?  Would the memo persist from session to session or would it be kindof purposeless in the web world?  Are there some examples of good places to use .memoize() in a grails app?

```
class DetermineStuffService{
  def figureThisOut(def whatever){
    //look up all sorts of stuff and do some heavy side-effect free processing
    return nastyHashmap
  }
}
```

So in a controller can I somehow call `DetermineStuffService.figureThisOut(someRandomObject)` and take advantage of `.memoize()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with this is that `memoize()` only works on closures.  Closures are objects, so if you store one in your service, it is "state".

A better way of caching services in grails is with the [Spring Cache plugin](http://gpc.github.com/grails-springcache/docs/guide/index.html).  Then to cache the result of a service method, just annotate the method with `@Cacheable`.  It has support for multiple caches, automatically flushing, and caching controller output as well.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer.  To be clear: we are agreeing that .memoize() does not make sense in normal web apps because it goes against the principle of stateless, correct?

Comment: Well, caching is stateful by definition.  However, the way spring cache does it fits into grails/spring better than `memoize()` since it keeps the state in one place, handles clustering properly, and doesn't require you to use closures instead of methods.